# Selection Sort troubles with keeping pointers in correct spots post sort

Tags: c, string, sorting, pointers, selection

I'm trying to execute a selection sort where i sort by the most goals scored. I have 3 categories; goals, assists, names. I can correctly sort by goals and keep the players goal's and assists in the correct spots after the sort, but when i try to move the names to the correct spot after the sort it only moves the first letter of the name. Here's my code. Thanks for the help!

```
void sortPlayersByGoals(int* goals, int* assists, char** names, int size)
{
    int lh, rh, i, tempG, tempA, tempN;
    for(lh = 0; lh < size; lh++)
    {
            rh = lh;
            for(i = lh; i < size; i++)
            {
                    if(goals[i] > goals[rh])
                    {
                            rh = i;
                    }
            tempG = goals[lh];
            tempA = assists[lh];
            tempN = *names[lh];
            goals[lh] = goals[rh];
            *names[lh] = *names[rh];
            assists[lh] = assists[rh];
            goals[rh] = tempG;
            *names[rh] = tempN;
            assists[rh] = tempA;
            }
    }

}
```

Here's my output if that helps show my problem..

```
Pre-Sort
Name                       Goals                   Assists
Redden                         2                         0
Berglund                       5                         2
Jackman                        2                         0
Stewart                        4                         0
Oshie                          3                         5
McDonald                       2                         4
Pietrangelo                    2                         7
Perron                         2                         6
Tarasenko                      5                         5
Post-Sort
Name                       Goals                   Assists
Tedden                         5                         5
Berglund                       5                         2
Sackman                        4                         0
Otewart                        3                         5
Rshie                          2                         0
McDonald                       2                         4
Pietrangelo                    2                         7
Perron                         2                         6
Jarasenko                      2                         0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void sortPlayersByGoals(int* goals, int* assists, char** names, int size)
{               /*  names is an array of pointers to char   */
    int lh, rh, i, tempG, tempA;
    char *tempN;     /* a pointer to one name */
    for(lh = 0; lh < size; lh++)
    {
            rh = lh;
            for(i = lh; i < size; i++)
            {
                    if(goals[i] > goals[rh])
                    {
                            rh = i;
                    }
            tempG = goals[lh];
            tempA = assists[lh];
            tempN = names[lh]; /* names[lh] is a pointer to the name in pos lh */
            goals[lh] = goals[rh];
            names[lh] = names[rh]; /* swap the pointers */
            assists[lh] = assists[rh];
            goals[rh] = tempG;
            names[rh] = tempN;  /* and not just the first letter */
            assists[rh] = tempA;
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the relevant character copying code you have:

```
int tempN;
...
tempN = *names[lh];
*names[lh] = *names[rh];
*names[rh] = tempN;
```

Your "names" variable is a `char**` (I'll assume it's instantiated as an array of `char*` which you then pass as a pointer), so when you perform `*names[lh]`, you're first indexing into your `char**` to get the `char*` at index `lh`, then dereferencing it. This is the same thing as indexing into the 0th element of the `char*` at index lh, which gives you its 1st character. Since you do this for all of your names-related operations, you're only ever just moving around the 1st character of your names. Also, your `tempN` variable is declared as an int, which is probably not what you intended.

You can fix it (with the smallest modification to your code) by looping over the length of the name you want to copy and assigning it character by character (instead of just the 1st character as you're doing now). Or you can use strcpy (or one of its variants, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6xf663%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for a reference)

On a side note, if at all possible I would advocate for you just using strings instead. Also, you might want to think about having your data more tightly coupled, i.e. having a list of player structs that holds the player's {name, goals, and assists} and just re-arranging your list, but I guess that's a design decision that's up to you.